# Unexpected '=>' when adding array element

Tags: php

I'm trying to add an array element so that it can be referenced as:

```
$url_list['some_id']['url']
```

and

```
$url_list['some_id']['time']
```

Here is the code:

```
$url_list[] = [ $eswc_id ][ 'url' => wp_get_referer(), 'time' => time() ];
```

It causes an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting
>   ']'

I'm new to PHP, I tried `$eswc_id` without the brackets and `$url_list +=` instead of `$url_list[] =` but I'm getting the same error, how can I fix the syntax?

Comment: please read documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: Try this $url_list[$eswc_id ] = [ 'url' => wp_get_referer(), 'time' => time() ];

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. Perhaps `$url_list[$eswc_id] = ['url' => ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to that ID directly like this:

```
$url_list[$eswc_id] = [ 'url' => wp_get_referer(), 'time' => time() ];
```

---

The way you're doing it now,

- `[ $eswc_id ]` creates a new array, and then
- `[ 'url' => wp_get_referer(), 'time' => time() ]` tries to immediately dereference the array, but the arrow is not correct syntax to dereference.

That's kind of irrelevant since it's not what you're trying to do anyway, but that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I want to create a new ID with this piece of code.

Comment: I thought `$eswc_id` was the a new ID that you had already created. I guess I misunderstood. So what is `$eswc_id` then?

Comment: Maybe he wants `$url_list[] = array($eswc_id => array('url' => wp_get_referer(), 'time' => time()));`

Comment: @Cid thanks, I wanted exactly this! I used this structure a couple of months ago, but it escaped me!

Comment: @Don'tPanic feel free to use my comment in your answer

Comment: @Ryszard With `$url_list[] = ...` you won't be able to access your entries as `$url_list['some_id']` though, it'll be `$url_list[0]['some_id']`…

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk With that syntax, it is not possible to access the array the way you showed in the question. To get to url you would need `$url_list[an int]['some_id']['url']` rather than `$url_list['some_id']['url']`.

Comment: Yep, that's either a badly asked question about the expected result or he's wrong about what I suggested